# Heavy CPU Usage on pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, pthreads

I have simple Application which receives messages through TCP Socket and process the same messages and Perform Some Actions.

I have used std::queue's to store the messages and process them on a thread.

Application is working fine with no crash. But, after few minutes the application consumes heavy cpu.

Here is my insert message and process message ( thread) code

My Simple Queue and thread veriables

```
std::queue<std::string> in_data_queue;
pthread_mutex_t in_data_queue_lock=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t in_data_queue_condition=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Code For Processing Queue

```
void *processMessage(void *attr) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&in_data_queue_lock) == 0) {
                if (!in_data_queue.empty()) {
                    std::string data = in_data_queue.front();
                    in_data_queue.pop();
                    pthread_cond_signal(&in_data_queue_condition);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&in_data_queue_lock);
                    // do some action ;
                } else {
                    pthread_cond_wait(&in_data_queue_condition,
                        &in_data_queue_lock);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&in_data_queue_lock);
                }
            }
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }
        cout << "processMessage" << endl;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Code For Insert the Message in Queue

```
void pushMessage(std::string rData) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&in_data_queue_lock);
   in_data_queue.push(rData);
   pthread_cond_signal(&in_data_queue_condition);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&in_data_queue_lock);
}
```

Any body help me what's the wrong with thread. Is that fine implementation or any issue on this thread. Please help me..

Comment: [Off Topic] Do note that if you have C++11 or higher support you can use [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread) which, IMHO, is a lot easier to use then `pthreads`.

Comment: "... no crash. But, after few minutes the application consumes heavy cpu. ", this can be caused by running out of memory  The cpu loads up because it starts shuffling data into and out of swap.  On Linux, you can use 'System Monitor' and click the "resources tab" to view memory and swap activity.  You did not show enough code ... are you using a fixed number of buffers?

Comment: Could it be that "*after few minutes*" the application does not receive anything any more and therefore `processMessage()` goes into a busy-waiting state, due to calling `pthread_mutex_trylock()` which then constantly fails? And BTW regarding debugging: Does the "real" code also completely miss any error checking for those `pthread_*()` calls?